# Debug flutter console fills up with random error messages

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, shader, skia

Sometimes, when I reload the app or restart it, I see a lot of messages like this in the debug console:

"
D/skia    ( 7858): Shader compilation error

D/skia    ( 7858): ------------------------

D/skia    ( 7858): Errors:

D/skia    ( 7858):
"

What should I do? The app works perfect. It happens with every app.

Comment: I've the same problem